# Retrieve value of same key (from user input) in nested object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a file of `data.js` look like this:

```
const data = {
  usr1: {
    name: "Abby Middleston",
    age: "34",
    gender: "female",
    userId: "0001",
  },
  usr2: {
    name: "Tom Hardy",
    age: "19",
    gender: "male",
    userId: "0002",
  },
  usr3: {
    name: "George Smith",
    age: "58",
    gender: "male",
    userId: "0003",
  },
  usr4: {
    name: "Kate Winston",
    age: "70",
    gender: "female",
    userId: "0004",
  },
  usr5: {
    name: "Abby LaMere",
    age: "20",
    gender: "female",
    userId: "0005",
  },
};
```

The user will input a filter like `"age == 34"` (I have finished processing the string) and the result will be true or false. I have tried `Object.key` and `Array.forEach` but none of them worked (or I may have done it wrong!)
How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.values` and `some` is what you need here:

```js
const data = { usr1: { name: "Abby Middleston", age: "34", gender: "female", userId: "0001", }, usr2: { name: "Tom Hardy", age: "19", gender: "male", userId: "0002", }, usr3: { name: "George Smith", age: "58", gender: "male", userId: "0003", }, usr4: { name: "Kate Winston", age: "70", gender: "female", userId: "0004", }, usr5: { name: "Abby LaMere", age: "20", gender: "female", userId: "0005", }};

var result = Object.values(data).some(({age})=>age==34);

console.log(result);
```